# How do you get a formatted/indented JSON String from a JSON object?

Tags: json, dart

Using `dart:convert` I can get an unindented string with this code.

```
var unformattedString = JSON.encode(jsonObject);
```

How do I take a JSON object and convert it to an indented string?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

One way to do it is by creating a JSONEncoder.withIndent instance.

```
String getPrettyJSONString(jsonObject){
   var encoder = new JsonEncoder.withIndent("     ");
   return encoder.convert(jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: jsonObject is of type Map?

Comment: @OliverDixon the documentation contains the types it takes (including Map) https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/JsonEncoder/convert.html

Answer (score 8):

Use this. it worked for me

```
String prettyJson(dynamic json) {
    var spaces = ' ' * 4;
    var encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent(spaces);
    return encoder.convert(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the existing answers cover the basics, if you're dealing with a map containing complex values like enums or dates, here's an effective method:

1. **Prepare the Map**: Use `makeMapEncodable(map)` from the [flutter_helper_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils) package. This function ensures all map values are JSON-compatible, crucial for complex data types.
2. **Generate JSON**: Convert the prepared map to an indented JSON string using `JsonEncoder`.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_helper_utils/flutter_helper_utils.dart';

final yourMap = {
  'id': 2,
  'firstName': 'John',
  'lastName': 'Doe',
  'timePeriod': TimePeriod.week, // Example enum.
  'date': DateTime.now(),
};

final encodableMap = makeMapEncodable(yourMap);
final json = const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ').convert(encodableMap);
print(json);
```

**Resulting JSON**:

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "timePeriod": "week",
  "date": "2024-01-06 12:31:13.915016"
}
```

**Why `makeMapEncodable`?**
It processes the map to handle non-standard JSON types (enums, DateTime, etc.), ensuring no runtime errors and a correctly formatted JSON output.

For more utilities, check the [flutter_helper_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils) documentation [here](https://flutter-helper-utils.web.app).